# Why can’t I see the selected values in the multi-select widget?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

The values I selected in my multi-select widget below showing up as N/A. Where did I go wrong in my configuration and how  can I set it up correctly?[image: widget set up and error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional `displayValues` attribute, defined in the "Display" field, sets the values displayed in the multi-select box. You can see the screenshots below:

[image: show widget set up]
[image: shows display values]

Moving to the `</>` tab, if you set values for `“selectedDisplayValues”` then it will display those values rather than the `“selectedValues”`. When you set `“SelectedDisplayValues”: []` you are telling Slate that there are no values to display. If instead you set `“SelectedDisplayValues” = “”` Slate would read this as no values entered in this field. Therefore, the widget will display the values configured in `{{f_function1}}` instead.

[image: configuration example]

You check see more details about the multi-select widget [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/widgets-control/#multiselect-box-widget).